# Visual Studio 2017 not building project

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution with .net core 2.0 project and .net framework 6.0 projects referenced inside the .net core 2.0 project

It was building fine, then a colleague faced a situation where project started to fail building using visual studio and he had to build it using: `dotnet build` in cmd.

This issue travelled through source control to hit me too.

This is the error I am getting when trying to build.

> project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to
>   generate this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others' reference, solved this issue by updating Visual studio to v15.5.2